# Tricks in Complex analysis, but not possible in Real analysis or Quaternion analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, number-theory, quaternions

1. What are some fundamental reasons that Complex analysis in $\mathbb{C}$ is more powerful, but it is not possible to generalize to the Real analysis in $\mathbb{R}$ or the Quaternion analysis in $\mathbb{H}$? What makes the $\mathbb{C}$ more special than the Real $\mathbb{R}$ or Quaternion $\mathbb{H}$?
2. What are some tricks that can be done in Complex analysis, but not possible in Real analysis or Quaternion analysis?

Here I provide additional details: for example in complex analysis, we have the Riemann zeta function. But there is no obvious counterpart in real analysis or in quaternion analysis.

Comment: $\mathbb H$ is for [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion), $\mathbb Q$ is for rationals.

Comment: Yes just a notation issue - fixed - no need to downvote for this profound issue... +1

Comment: I didn't downvote. Possibly it was because your question is not specific enough.

Comment: Complex differentiable = analytic is a very strong property.

Comment: Vaguely speaking, one reason to complex analysis is «more powerful» than real analysis is by the geometric of the spaces. In $\mathbb{R}$ you only have two ways to aproximate to a point (left and right), whereas in $\mathbb{C}$ you have a lot (really a lot) ways to aproximate to a point (over a curve, in a straight line and, generally, any path that you can imagine inside an open ball).

Comment: thanks for nice comments. But how about in Quaternion ℍ?

Comment: I think it all comes down to the definition of derivatives. In real analysis, we say that $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is differentiable at $a$ if there is *some* linear map $L(h)$ which is a $o(||h||)$ approximation to $f(a+h) - f(a)$. In complex analysis, we say that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ (thinking of $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$) is differentiable if there is a linear map $L(h)$ which is a *pure rotation + dilation* which is a  $o(||h||)$ approximation to $f(a+h) - f(a).$

Comment: As for point 2, forget analysis and just think about algebra, in $\Bbb{C}$ you know that every quadratic polynomial has exactly two roots (modulo multiplicity). Life is much more interesting in $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{H}$.

Comment: (continued from previous comment) So Complex differentiable maps are a small subset of real differentiable maps, therefore we expect to be able to say much more about them.

Comment: A common "trick" in complex analysis is the use of contour integrals and residues to obtain closed forms for real integrals such as $\int_0^{\infty}\frac {1}{1+x^4}dx$ that are resistant to real analysis.

Comment: @daniel that integral is actually fairly easy by real analysis, if you use the [Sophie Germain factorization](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/SophieGermainIdentity.shtml). Partial fractions in real analysis are actually an implementation of the Residue Theorem.

Comment: thanks can you help to reopen my question? (so I may be able to accept more answers)

Answer (score 3):

One operation where complex analysis fits is [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), which is defined for integer heights as $^2x=x^x$, $^3x=x^{x^x}$, etc. If we try to interpolate to define the operation for fractional "power-tower" heights, there are many ways to do it. But in complex analysis a unique interpolation with a single branch cut in the complex plane is defined:

> It has now been proven[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10444-017-9524-1) that there exists a unique function F which is a solution of the equation F(z + 1) = exp(F(z)) and satisfies the additional conditions that F(0) = 1 and F(z) approaches the fixed points of the logarithm (roughly 0.318 ± 1.337i) as z approaches ±i∞ and that F is holomorphic in the whole complex z-plane, except the part of the real axis at z ≤ −2. This proof confirms a previous conjecture.[[2]](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-09-02188-7) The construction of such a function was originally demonstrated by Kneser in 1950.[3] The complex map of this function is shown in the figure at right. The proof also works for other bases besides e, as long as the base is bigger than ${\displaystyle e^{\frac {1}{e}}\approx 1.445}$. Subsequent work extended the construction to all complex bases. The complex double precision approximation of this function is available online.[[4]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10444-018-9615-7)

**Cited references**

1.
Paulsen, W.; Cowgill, S. (March 2017). "Solving ${\displaystyle F(z+1)=b^{F(z)}}$ in the complex plane" (PDF). *Advances in Computational Mathematics* **43**: 1–22. doi:10.1007/s10444-017-9524-1. S2CID 9402035.

2.
Kouznetsov, D. (July 2009). "Solution of ${\displaystyle F(z+1)=\exp(F(z))}$ in complex $z$-plane" (PDF). *Mathematics of Computation* **78** (267): 1647–1670. doi:10.1090/S0025-5718-09-02188-7.

3.
Kneser, H. (1950). "Reelle analytische Lösungen der Gleichung ${\displaystyle \varphi {\Big (}\varphi (x){\Big )}={\rm {e}}^{x}}$ und verwandter Funktionalgleichungen". *Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik* (in German). **187**: 56–67.

4.
Paulsen, W. (June 2018). "Tetration for complex bases". *Advances in Computational Mathematics*. **45**: 243–267. doi:10.1007/s10444-018-9615-7. S2CID 67866004.

Comment: thanks can you help to reopen my question? (so I may be able to accept answer)